# Type error occurs randomly when invoking click event rapidly

Tags: javascript, html

I was creating a small javascript applet that would spawn a new button just once when the new button has not been clicked before. However, when you click on the buttons rapidly, I randomly get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined". Why would this occur?

Code: "https://codepen.io/fyun89/pen/PgWMNg?editors=1111"

```
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
let container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

const action = function(e) {
  // set up new button
  let newBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newBtn.innerHTML = 'this is has been clicked <span>0</span> times';

  // for new button decoration
  let color1 = Math.min(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000)/3), 255);
  let color2 = Math.min(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000)/3), 255);
  let color3 = Math.min(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000)/3), 255);

  // if the button hasn't been clicked
  if (e.target.children[0].innerHTML < 1) {
    container[0].appendChild(newBtn);

    // target the last created child - button
    let currentElem = container[0].children;
    currentElem[currentElem.length - 1].setAttribute('class', 'btn');
    currentElem[currentElem.length - 1].style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${color1}, ${color2}, ${color3})`;
    currentElem[currentElem.length - 1].addEventListener('click', action);
  }

  // get the current element's count
  let numb = Number(e.target.children[0].innerHTML);
  e.target.children[0].innerHTML = numb + 1;
}

for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', action);
}
```

[image: Image with error in console]

Comment: never throws an error no matter how fast I click

Comment: can't reproduce the error on codepen

Comment: Neither can I reproduce the issue

Comment: can't reproduce the error

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: @Jaromanda X Holy crap you guys answered fast! That's really strange...I just tried this on another computer and it still happens. Did you try clicking newly created buttons too? The error is happening at line 15. It says it "cannot find innerHTML of undefined".

Comment: ok, let me rephrase ... *never throws an error no matter how fast or what I click*

Comment: @Jaromanda X This is interesting... Thank you for your input

Comment: It only happens if you click on the span/number  the span doesn't have any children since it's the target element in the event. Here's an article from our beloved codepen on the issue: https://css-tricks.com/slightly-careful-sub-elements-clickable-things/

Comment: What browser are you using @81ackCat ? Is there any extensions that you were using on the browser?

Comment: @81ackCat I've added some refactorings to my answer, I hope they prove to be useful (:

Comment: @Money Murch I was using Chrome and I certainly am using extensions such as Adblocker and such. But It looks like CTS_AE nailed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reproduce the issue by clicking on the number/span tag.

The span tag has no children and thus throws the error.

You can read more about how binding an event can trickle down to its children from our beloved creators of CodePen here:
https://css-tricks.com/slightly-careful-sub-elements-clickable-things/

**TLDR**; either check the element you're working with is the expected element, or add some CSS to prevent propagating downward (gross that CSS is controlling this IMHO...)

✨⭐ Or just replace `e.target` to `e.currentTarget` in your code, so that that bound element is being used rather than also including anything contained in it.

### Possible Fixes

#### CSS Method

You can do this if nothing inside of the button also needs click handling.

```css
.btn > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### JS Method

The commenters in the CSS Tricks article mention to use `currentTarget`.

I tried it and it seems to work

Just replace `e.target` to `e.currentTarget` in your code.

#### Another JS Method

```
const tagName = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
if (tagName === 'button') {
  // we have the button
}
else if (tagName === 'SPAN') {
  // we have the span
}
else {
  console.error('Unrecognized element', tagName, e.target)
}
```

### A Debug of the Error

When the error occurs notice the target is not the whole button it is just the span, and the span doesn't have any children.

This happens when you click on the number in the button (the span)

[image: Debugging the error]

### In Addition

From your code there is a spot where the event handler will not be bound for a very short period of time, but possibly exist in the DOM. I imagine due to rendering you may not even be able to click to find this bug, especially since it only exists on new buttons, but it programatically exists in the code for small period of time.

You should bind the click event before using `appendChild` to add it to the DOM. I would avoid adding your element to the DOM until you've styled, and added event handling.

*The red region denotes a time where the element exists in the DOM without a click handler.*

[image: Section where the event does not exist for a small period of time]

### Peer Review & Refactorings

#### Clean Up Round 1 - Maybe This Refactor Will Help?

I would recommend you use `const` instead of `let` if the variable is only assigned once and not expected to be reassigned. Although this may sound useless it can help shed some light on the intention of the variable you defined.

I've seen times were people have scoping and code issues and simply going through and setting the explicit `let` vs `const` helps shed some light on the issue.

In the refactor below I've changed `let` to `const` where applicable, as well as DRY'd the code up some, and made some parts more readable with descriptive variable names.

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

// name it for readability, but then run it
// let hosting bring action up
(function bindCurrentButtons() {
    for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', action);
  }
})();

function action(e) {
  // set up new button
  const newBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newBtn.innerHTML = 'this is has been clicked <span>0</span> times';

  // for new button decoration
  const randomColor = () => Math.min(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) / 3), 255);
  const colorRed = randomColor();
  const colorGreen = randomColor();
  const colorBlue = randomColor();

  // if the button hasn't been clicked
  if (e.target.children[0].innerHTML < 1) {
    // target the last created child - button
    const currentElemChildren = container[0].children;
    const elementIndex = currentElemChildren.length - 1;
    const currentElem = currentElemChildren[elementIndex];

    currentElem.setAttribute('class', 'btn');
    currentElem.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${colorRed}, ${colorGreen}, ${colorBlue})`;
    currentElem.addEventListener('click', action);

    container[0].appendChild(newBtn);
  }

  // get the current element's count
  const numb = Number(e.target.children[0].innerHTML);
  e.target.children[0].innerHTML = numb + 1;
}
```

#### Clean Up Round 2 - Continued Refactoring

Here's an updated CodePen. I did remove the classes to simplify it further.

https://codepen.io/fyun89/pen/PgWMNg?editors=1111

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

// name it for readability, but then run it right away
// let hosting bring other functions up
(function bindCurrentButtons() {
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', action);
  }
})();

function buttonCount(buttonElement) {
  const span = buttonElement.querySelector('span');
  return Number(span.innerText);
}

function incrementCounter(buttonElement) {
  const span = buttonElement.querySelector('span');
  const number = buttonCount(buttonElement) + 1;
  span.innerText = number.toString();
}

const randomColor = () => Math.min(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) / 3), 255);
const randomRgbColor = () => `rgb(${randomColor()}, ${randomColor()}, ${randomColor()})`;

function action(e) {
  const button = e.currentTarget;
  const currentCount = buttonCount(button);

  incrementCounter(button);

  if (currentCount === 0) {
    const newButton = createNewButton();
    container.appendChild(newButton);
  }
}

function createNewButton() {
  // set up new button
  const newButton = document.createElement('button');
  newButton.innerHTML = 'this is has been clicked <span>0</span> times';
  newButton.style.backgroundColor = randomRgbColor();
  newButton.addEventListener('click', action);
  return newButton;
}
```

#### Round 3 Refactoring - JS Classes

I've changed the HTML to not start with a button. The initial button is now created in the Javascript. It now starts with a random colored button instead of an orange button. The class now manages the state/counter. I also removed the span because it no longer needs to be used as a data store.

https://codepen.io/codyswartz/pen/GLmbvW?editors=0011

```js
  const randomColor = () => Math.min(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) / 3), 255);
  const randomRgbColor = () => `rgb(${randomColor()}, ${randomColor()}, ${randomColor()})`;

  class CounterButton {

    constructor(containerElement) {
      this.counter = 0;
      this.container = containerElement;
      this.button = this.createElement();

      this.updateCounter();
      this.randomBackgroundColor();
      this.bindClickEvent();
      this.addToDom();
    }

    createElement() {
      return document.createElement('button');
    }

    updateCounter() {
      this.button.innerHTML = `this is has been clicked ${this.counter} times`;
    }

    randomBackgroundColor() {
      this.button.style.backgroundColor = randomRgbColor();
    }

    bindClickEvent() {
      this.button.addEventListener('click', this.clickEvent.bind(this));
    }

    clickEvent() {
      if(this.counter === 0) {
        new CounterButton(this.container);
      }

      this.counter++;
      this.updateCounter();
    }

    addToDom() {
      this.container.appendChild(this.button);
    }

  }

  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  new CounterButton(container);
```

Comment: High-value answer and good sleuthing - +1. *PS - cool website*

Answer (score 1):

The error is not reproducible consistently. For short term, you can use the below code to get around the error.

```
 if (e.target.children.length > 0){
    if (e.target.children[0].innerHTML < 1) {
        container[0].appendChild(newBtn);
        // target the last created child - button
        let currentElem = container[0].children;
        currentElem[currentElem.length - 1].setAttribute('class', 'btn');
        currentElem[currentElem.length - 1].style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${color1}, ${color2}, ${color3})`;
        currentElem[currentElem.length - 1].addEventListener('click', action);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it useful to use a debouncer and see if that helps. You might already know, but a debouncer *ensures that only one signal is sent for an event that may be happening many, many times.* (Note also that there is also something called throttling, which limits the number of calls that a function receives during a fixed time interval - for example, only one event per 500ms.) Or, as [Chris Coyer explains the two](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/):

***Throttling enforces a maximum number of times a function can be called over time. As in "execute this function at most once every 100 milliseconds."***

and

***Debouncing enforces that a function not be called again until a certain amount of time has passed without it being called. As in "execute this function only if 100 milliseconds have passed without it being called."***

[In this article](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function), David Walsh explains this very popular debounce function, taken from [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce):

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

The example Walsh uses to demonstrate how to use the above function is:

```
var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
    // All the taxing stuff you do
}, 250);

window.addEventListener('resize', myEfficientFn);
```

References:

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

https://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: I like this to handle spastic clickers, but unfortunately it's not the reason his bug is occurring. The inner span tag inherits the same click handler, so then the code does not work because it was not the expected element.